# Input Placeholder text becoming input value when hiding and showing elements in angularjs view using IE

Tags: angularjs, input, placeholder

We have inputs with placeholders like this:

```
<input placeholder="Search..." type="text" />
```

Everything is fine in chrome/firefox, but in IE sometimes when we are hiding and showing the element, the placeholder becomes the input value -- you click on the input and your cursor is after the 3 dots of 
"Search...**(blinking cursor here)**"

The inputs are in an angularJS ngView and we use ngShow and ngHide to show/hide them based on various logic.

When the view first renders you can click in the input and it removes the placeholder as expected, but after the input is hidden and then shown once or twice the problem starts.

---

We have even tried recreating the browsers html5 placeholder behaviour with javascript, binding to its blur/focus events and using the inputs value but we actually get the same behavior attempting doing them that way too.

We originally tried to use a placeholder.js thinking it was related to IE 8 or less not being great with html5... but we get this issue in up to IE11 as well.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Maybe you can bind the focus event of the input and clear the placeholder with css `:-ms-input-placeholder{ display:none; } `

Comment: It would be extremely difficult to show it to you complete because it involves many files and views... here is a plunker it in general. I tested it in the plunker and the error does not happen... I think it is maybe due to the many scripts running routines in our app maybe they are causing the browser to somehow not keep up with the placeholder, but I am doubting that theory and am questioning mybe due to all of the showing and hiding we are doing maybe we are creating some bad html somewhere.  http://plnkr.co/edit/8fN1Mu8gZjZkse4eADLN?p=preview

Comment: Did you ever resolve this problem? I am experiencing pretty much the same problem in a simple input element generated by a portlet JSP. First click in the input element temporarily edits the placholder, and the second click actually allows me to input data that may be posted.

Comment: In my case the focus event somehow gets swallowed - and I end up being able to modify the displayed placedholder (temporarily). On the second click, the focus event is delivered and the input element behave as it should.