# Input element strange focus behavior on IE11

Tags: html, jsp, internet-explorer, liferay, placeholder

I have a Liferay 6.2 portlet whose view simply redirects to a JSP containing an `<input>` element with a placeholder, "Search" - this works beautifully in Chrome, but when I use IE11 the following bug occurs:

When I click **once** in the `<input>` element, I actually end up modifying the placeholder text when I type, and when I press enter, the submit does not occur. If I click a second time, the placeholder disappears, the `<input>` element only contains my typed text, and the submit occurs when I press enter.

#### The JSP file:

```html
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/ui" prefix="liferay-ui"%>
<%@ page import="javax.portlet.PortletPreferences"%>

<portlet:defineObjects />
<portlet:actionURL windowState="normal" var="actionURL" />

<li class="dropdown-toggle">
  <a class="search">
    <form action="<portlet:actionURL />" method="POST">
      <div>
        <span>
          <input type="text" name="<portlet:namespace />search"
                 placeholder="Search"></input>
          <i class="icon-search"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
    </form>
  </a>
</li>
```

#### The generated HTML:

```html
<li class="dropdown-toggle dockbar-item" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1426164600459_842">
  <a tabindex="0" class="search" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1426164600459_616">
    <form id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1426164600459_841" action="CENSORED" method="POST" lpsubmitorig="true" lpsubdone="1">
      <div id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1426164600459_840">
        <span id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1426164600459_839">
          <input name="_1_WAR_searchportlet_search" class="focus" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1426164600459_838" type="text" placeholder="Search" lpcachedvisval="0" lpcachedvistime="1426164601">
          <i class="icon-search"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
    </form>
  </a>
</li>
```

### Some other diagnostic information:

- This problem does not always occur the first time I try to input text in the `<input>`
- The attribute `class=""` does not change to `class="focus"` on the `<input>` element on the first click, but it does on the second. I've also put hooks on the focus and blur events and the problem occurs when I click into the `<input>` field and there is no corresponding focus event until I click a second time.
- when I cut/paste the HTML to a file and load it up in IE11, the `<input>` behaves like it should - I am wondering if some Liferay provided Javascript is causing the problem.
- I found a similar Stackoverflow question which has no answer:
  [Input Placeholder text becoming input value when hiding and showing elements in angularjs view using IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27515082/input-placeholder-text-becoming-input-value-when-hiding-and-showing-elements-in)

Comment: What do you want to achieve actually? Do you want to stop form submission or you want to control placeholder turning into field's value?

Comment: This is a case where I just want the `<input>` element to behave normally - in this case we have to click twice to get focus any subsequent clicks are alternating between blur and focus events to the `<input>`. The weird effect is that the first click into the `<input>` is not triggering a focus, but allows me to modify the placeholder itself. Real editing of the value does not occur until we actually get focus on the second click.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce issue with your code, but it is working fine (normal). On first click, field is getting focused and on pressing enter, form is being submitted.

Comment: I could not reproduce it in isolation. Did you reproduce it as a portlet in Liferay 6.2? We are thinking that something in the Liferay dockbar is interferring with the focus.

Comment: Yeah, I am too using Liferay 6.2, but issue is not reproducible.

Comment: Thanks for trying. We are working on a issue report for the Liferay team.